# How to do a nested loop with 2 columns for pandas dataframe with counter?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am using python and pandas. I have  a bunch of unstructured survey data.

I have a dataframe:

| Type | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| Sport | rowing |
| Sport | Surfing |
| Sport | Basketball |
| Sport | Dancing |
| Sport | Dancing |
| Studies | science |
| Studies | Math |
| Studies | History |

I have survey data that says:
"Sarah does Basketball and Math"
"Kilian does Math"
"Lorenzo does history"
"Robert does dancing"
"Rachel does basketball and dancing"
I want a table that says which students do one or the other and which students do both. (the real data has 30 different sub categories)

I want to create a table like below:

| Student | Sports | Studies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Sarah does Basketball and Math" | 1 | 1 |
| "Kilian does Math" | 0 | 1 |
| ""Lorenzo does history" | 0 | 1 |
| "Robert does dancing" | 1 | 0 |
| "Rachel does basketball and dancing" | 2 | 0 |

I think I need to say

```
Distinct_Activities = dataframe.Activity.nunique()
```

#split survey data to be a list of words.
counter = 0
Then say:

```
For i in Survey_data: 
   while j = Disitinct_Activities[0]
```

- if you compare a list of words from sentence and your words in data frame where type = sport and one Activity is similar then counter +1  then go to the next Activity till you finish that type.  then  return count in a dictionary to a column for how many times it hit that section.  then go to next sentence and compare all activities in #Activity or go to next part of Distinct_Activities[1]
  Then loop back up to next sentence once done.

I am struggling figuring out how to loop through the dataframe using type and activity. I tried to create 30 different lists and dataframes but that didn't go well. Can anyone help me create this inner loop strategy.

---

PROGRESS and ERROR

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# read the Type_Activity, Student files
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

# create a dictionary with (activity, Type)
   ### activity_type = dict(zip(df1['Activity'].str.lower(), df1['Type'].str.lower()))
 activity_type = df1.groupby('Type')['Activity'].apply(list).to_dict()
    
df2 = df2.join( # join the df2 with the new dataframe
    pd.json_normalize( # convert the dictionaries into columns
        df2['Student'].apply( # apply the following function on the "Student" column
            lambda x: Counter([ # count the types
                type_ 
                for activity in x.strip().lower().split() # lower then split the student text into words
                for type_ in [activity_type.get(activity)] # just a hack to ignore the normal words
                if type_ # the hole purpose of the pervoius line is to add this check
            ])
        )
    ).fillna(0) # fill the NAN values with zeros then convert to int for better look
)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/06082022_CreateFactorization.py", line 33, in <module>
    pd.json_normalize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7841, in applymap
    return self.apply(infer).__finalize__(self, "applymap")
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7765, in apply
    return op.get_result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 185, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 276, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 290, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7839, in infer
    return lib.map_infer(x.astype(object)._values, func, ignore_na=ignore_na)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Counter'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid loops as much as possible, here we replaced the 2 loops with a dictionary `activity_type` that maps every activity to its type.

NOTE: the `df1` is the Type, Activity `DataFrame`

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# read the Type_Activity, Student files
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

# create a dictionary with (activity, Type)
activity_type = dict(zip(df1['Activity'].str.lower(), df1['Type'].str.lower()))

df2 = df2.join( # join the df2 with the new dataframe
    pd.json_normalize( # convert the dictionaries into columns
        df2['Student'].apply( # apply the following function on the "Student" column
            lambda x: Counter([ # count the types
                type_ 
                for activity in x.strip().lower().split() # lower then split the student text into words
                for type_ in [activity_type.get(activity)] # just a hack to ignore the normal words
                if type_ # the hole purpose of the pervoius line is to add this check
            ])
        )
    ).fillna(0) # fill the NAN values with zeros then convert to int for a better look
)
```

**update:**

my `activity_type` dictionary was mapping the activity to a single string (type), assuming that every activity has only one type.

your `activity_type` dictionary was mapping the activity to a list of types, which will be better if activities may have more than one type.

NOTE: I changed it to `set` instead of `list` to avoid duplications and for better performance.

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# read the Type_Activity, Student files
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

# lower case the columns then create a dictionary with (activity, [Types])
df1[['Activity', 'Type']] = df1[['Activity', 'Type']].applymap(lambda x: x.lower())
activity_types = df1.groupby('Activity')['Type'].apply(set).to_dict()

# join the df2 with the new dataframe
df2 = df2.join(
    # convert the dictionaries into columns
    pd.json_normalize(
        # apply the following function on the "Student" column
        df2['Student'].apply(
            # count the types
            lambda x: Counter([
                type_ 
                # lower then split the student text into words
                for activity in x.strip().lower().split()
                # ignore the normal words
                for type_ in activity_types.get(activity, [])
            ])
        )
    ).fillna(0).applymap(int) # fill the NAN values with zeros then convert to int for better look
)
```

**output:**

| Student | sport | studies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah does Basketball and Math | 1 | 1 |
| Kilian does Math | 0 | 1 |
| Lorenzo does history | 0 | 1 |
| Robert does dancing | 1 | 0 |
| Rachel does basketball and dancing | 2 | 0 |

Comment: its making the types the columns headers instead of the activities.